# Zend Form Decorator on 1.12 version

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

Hi all I'm trying to render this html structure with Zend :

```
<div id="medias" class="item">
    <h2> Medias </h2>
    <a id="addmedia" href="#">
        <img alt="" src="images/bigbtn-add.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

## Update 1 :

This is how I create the media_img element :

```
$media_img = new Zend_Form_Element_Image('media_img');
$media_img->setImage("/img/bigbtn-add.png");
$this->addElement($media_img);
```

Using this :

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'HtmlTag', array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'a', 'id' => 'addmedia','href' => '#'))
),
array('media_img')
);
```

I properly render this part of my code :

```
<a id="addmedia" href="#">
    <img alt="" src="images/bigbtn-add.png">
</a>
```

How can I prepend the h2 and then wrap these elements inside my div ?

## Update 2 :

Thanks to @Mubo's help, I render this html :

```
<h2 class="hint">Medias</h2>
<a id="addmedia" href="#">
    <input id="media_img" type="image" src="/img/bigbtn-add.png" name="media_img">
</a>
```

Now I only need to wrap all of these lines in a div.
The decorator looks like this now :

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'HtmlTag', array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'a', 'id' => 'addmedia','href' => '#')),
    array('Description', array('tag' => 'h2', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
),
array('media_img')
);
```

What's missing ?

Thanks for your help.

## Update 3 : I still can't figure it out...

Comment: Are you using some complicated decorators for all elements or you are interested only write decorator for this one field? Because another option is render this form manually and you can define this markup there.

Comment: Just use HTML manually.

Comment: @s7anley I would like to use only decorators to achieve this.
If I can how it works, this is much better. I'm lost !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I finally found a solution. Here is my decorator :

```
   $media_img->setDecorators(array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'a', 'id' => 'addmedia','href' => '#')),
        array('Description', array('tag' => 'h2', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
        array(
            array('fieldDiv' => 'HtmlTag'), 
            array(
                'tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'item', 'id' => 'medias'
            )
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  setDescription and prepend it with decorator like this.

This is very tricky and not straightforward.

```
     $myElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
      $myElement->setLabel('Label');       
      $myElement->setRequired(true);
      $myElement->setDescription('Medias');        
      $myElement->setDecorators(   array(  'DijitElement', 'Errors',
                array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
                array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
                array('Description', array('tag' => 'h2', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
                array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr', 'class' => 'form_row'))
            ));
$this->addElement($myElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I tried to integrate your decorator to mine but I can't render it like in my example. Could you please take my example as a reference ?

Comment: i don't know what you mean , I have tested the code and it worked for me. in your controller instantiate the form class. and assign it to the view and in your view html just echo the code. if you don't know all about this I may give you an Example

Comment: You are using tr tags. How can I obtain this structure : 

`<div id="medias" class="item">
    <h2> Medias </h2>
    <a id="addmedia" href="#">
        <img alt="" src="images/bigbtn-add.png">
    </a>
</div>`

Comment: It seems what you want to do is different from what is written there. I you want prepend h2 TAG  on the element form. that what is wrote.

Comment: This has nothing to do with zend form. the following code you wrote to me is just plain HTML and image link.   <div id="medias" class="item">
 <h2>Medias</h2>
 <a id="addmedia" href="#"> <img alt="" src="images/bigbtn-add.png"> </a>
</div>

Comment: My decorator outputs this plain html without the <div> for the moment. How can I add it now ?